# TFTP Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tftp

I have set up tftp server but having trouble testing / accessing from remote platforms

Setup:

```
sudo apt update;
sudo apt install -y tftpd-hpa;
sudo ufw allow tftp;
put files in
/var/lib/tftpboot
```

testing from the remote machine times out (firewall disabled)

```
tftp 109.228.38.69
tftp> get test.txt
Transfer timed out.
tftp>quit
```

While testing locally however on the actual server:

```
tftp 127.0.0.1
tftp> get test.txt
Received 11 bytes in 0.0 seconds
tftp>quit
```

The server is hosted on Virtual Private Server with https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/

UFW status

69/udp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

EDIT:

```
 sudo lsof -i:69
```

returns

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
in.tftpd 6874 root    4u  IPv4  90405      0t0  UDP *:tftp   
in.tftpd 6874 root    5u  IPv6  90406      0t0  UDP *:tftp
```

cannot find much about in.tftp - is this a built in service ?
Which is better to use and where are its files stored.

Comment: Take a look at that answer, looks similar https://serverfault.com/a/599112

Comment: sorry that is not the same issue

Comment: Did you find an answer?